# Open child window on link button click present in DevExpress GridControl and pass values

Tags: silverlight, devexpress, gridcontrol

I am doing silverlight 4 app.

I have DevExpress GridControl with 4 columns. I have placed HyperlinkButton as display template for one of columns as it shown below. The item source of the gridcontrol has bound in code-behind.

```
<dxg:GridControl Name="grid" Height="294" Width="634">
    <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Name" />
        <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Id_no" />
        <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Type" />
        <dxg:GridColumn Header="View Details">
            <dxg:GridColumn.DisplayTemplate>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <HyperlinkButton Click="HyperlinkButton_Click"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </dxg:GridColumn.DisplayTemplate>
        </dxg:GridColumn>
    </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
```

Within the HyperlinkButton's Click eventhandler I want to open a child window and pass details(Name,Id_no,Type) of that **particular row** to it.

```
void HyperlinkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    Childwin win_ch = new Childwin();
    win_ch.Show();
    // pass the row values to the child window???
}
```

Don't know how get **row values of the gridcontrol.**

Any ideas? Is there a better method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get row handle of a grid's row that contains the hyperlink via the [DataViewBase.GetRowHandleByTreeElement](http://help.devexpress.com/#Silverlight/DevExpressXpfGridDataViewBase_GetRowHandleByTreeElementtopic) method. Then use the [GridControl.GetRow](http://help.devexpress.com/#Silverlight/DevExpressXpfGridGridControl_GetRowtopic) method to obtain the row object.

```
void HyperlinkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    int rowHandle = tableView3.GetRowHandleByTreeElement((DependencyObject)sender);
    object row = gridControl1.GetRow(rowHandle);
    // then use the row object
}
```

Please also review the following help articles:

1. [Obtaining Row Handles](http://help.devexpress.com/#Silverlight/CustomDocument5179)
2. [Identifying Rows](http://help.devexpress.com/#Silverlight/CustomDocument5178)